# Open One File-type per Tab

Tags: filetype, tabbed-user-interface

In vim you can open all files in present directory with `vim *`.

All of a specific file type in directory with `vim *.py`.

Recursively we use `vim **/*` and `vim **/*.py`.

To open all files in tabs `vim -p *`. Recursively `vim -p **/*`

Is there a way to open specific file types in specific tabs recursively? Lets say all `.py` in tab 1, all `.js` files in tab 2, all `.html` files in tab3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do what you want, but I've just learned that that's not the way you're supposed to use tabs. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers/103590#103590) was very useful to me, and maybe it can help you too.

Comment: That link got me clearer about tabs. I have been using vim with just buffers and fuzzy finder but thought I would look into tabs.  Now I understand tabs I don't see a purpose for them and can happily continue to work with buffers as I have been hehe.